# sicktoolbox hydro error

Tags: ros, laser, ros-hydro, sicktoolbox-wrapper, sick

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello folks,

I am using Sick LM291 and usb serial converter.
Ubuntu 12.04 intell 64 bits and hydro.

In fuerte, there was no problem to use this laser but we recently change the ros version and this is the output of the laser LM291 sicktoolbox_wrapper:

```
   $ rosrun sicktoolbox_wrapper sicklms

    *** Attempting to initialize the Sick LMS...
    Attempting to open device @ /dev/ttyUSB0
        Device opened!
    Attempting to start buffer monitor...
        Buffer monitor started!
    Attempting to set requested baud rate...
A Timeout Occurred! 2 tries remaining
A Timeout Occurred! 1 tries remaining
A Timeout Occurred - SickLIDAR::_sendMessageAndGetReply: Attempted max number of tries w/o success!
    Failed to set requested baud rate...
    Attempting to detect LMS baud rate...
        Checking 19200bps...
A Timeout Occurred! 2 tries remaining
A Timeout Occurred! 1 tries remaining
A Timeout Occurred - SickLIDAR::_sendMessageAndGetReply: Attempted max number of tries w/o success!
        Checking 38400bps...
        Detected LMS baud @ 38400bps!
        Operating @ 38400bps
    Attempting to sync driver...
        Driver synchronized!
    *** Init. complete: Sick LMS is online and ready!
    Sick Type: Sick LMS 291-S05
    Scan Angle: 100 (deg)
    Scan Resolution: 0.25 (deg)
    Measuring Mode: 8m/80m; fields A,B,Dazzle
    Measuring Units: Centimeters (cm)

[ INFO] [1410366255.940479716]: Variant setup not requested or identical to actual (100, 0.250000)
[ INFO] [1410366255.940548802]: Measuring units setup not requested or identical to actual ('Centimeters (cm)')
[ WARN] [1410366255.940781220]: You are using an angle smaller than 180 degrees and a scan resolution less than 1 degree per scan. Thus, you are in inteleaved mode and the returns will not arrive sequentially how you read them. So, the time_increment field will be misleading. If you need to know when the measurement was made at a time resolution better than the scan_time, use the whole 180 degree field of view.
    Requesting measured value data stream...
        Data stream started!
A Timeout Occurred - SickLIDAR::_recvMessage: Timeout occurred!
[ERROR] [1410366261.971579984]: Unknown error.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'SickToolbox::SickThreadException'
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The most strange thing is that the node indentify correctly the laser but when try to publish, appear segmentation fault with unknown error.

Tell me if I am doing something wrong or is just package problem. Some related problems but not the same here:

http://answers.ros.org/question/99096/using-sicktoolbox-on-hydro/

Best regards.

************* EDIT ***************
I try it in indigo and it works fine. Maybe some problem related to hydro branch?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192409/sicktoolbox-hydro-error/) by [pmarinplaza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1959/pmarinplaza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2014-09-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use the option connect_delay

rosrun sicktoolbox_wrapper sicklms _port:=/dev/ttyUSB0 _connect_delay:=30

or

rosparam set sicklms/port /dev/ttyUSB0
rosparam set sicklms/connect_delay 30
rosrun sicktoolbox_wrapper sicklms

---

Originally posted by [izquierdocr](https://answers.ros.org/users/21680/izquierdocr/) with karma: 16 on 2015-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0